# Processing Future Comprehension Scala

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have an actor the receives a message and runs two futures.  Those futures can run in parallel, so I thought I could use a for comprehension to run both futures and combine their result into one response to the sender.  I can get the results from each by themselves, but I don't know what to do to get aggregate them when they are both complete.

```
def receive = {
    case "pcbStatus" => {
      val currentSender = sender
      //first future
      val wsf = (self ? "workhorseStats")(5 seconds)

      val psf = Future.traverse(context.children)(x => {
        (x ? "reportStatus")(5 seconds)
      });

      val combined = for {
        r1 <- wsf
        r2 <- psf
      } yield (r1, r2)



      combined.onComplete {
        case Success(result:Any) => {
          val response = new SomeCaseClass(r1,r2)
          println("YAY: " + response)
          currentSender ! response
        }
        case Failure(failure) => {
          println("FAIL: " + failure)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But you already get a Future[(Int,Int)] (or whatever type your wsf an psf are), and unwrapping it in onComplete, so what is the problem?

Comment: I want to take the results (r1 and r2) and create a response with them...  Updating code to reflect

Comment: Where you write `new SomeCaseClass(r1, r2)`, neither `r1` nor `r2` are in scope. However, you can match on `case Success((r1, r2)) =>` and skip that nasty `Any` business.

Comment: @RandallSchulz that times out, any other ideas?

Comment: You're `ask`ing `self` but your Actor has no case to respond to `"workhorseStats"`. Naturally the awaits time out.

Comment: Try to use something like this: ... yield new SomeCaseClass(r1, r2).map(responce => currentSender ! responce).recover {...}

Comment: This may be off topic but why use ask to self?  At that point you are already in the actor and thus have access to all internal state and methods. Why go back out to come back in and incur another mailbox hit there?

Comment: @cmbaxter thanks for the comments.  The other receive for the self is there because I'm using that method from other actors, and not just internally.  I could refactor to have the logic internally, and just have any code path that needs it execute that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've coded a little example of what I think it is you are trying to do.  First, the two actor classes:

```
class ParentActor extends Actor{
  import context._
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)      

  override def preStart = {
    context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], "child-a")
    context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], "child-b")
  }    

  def receive = {
    case "foo" =>
      val fut1 = (self ? "bar").mapTo[Int]
      val fut2 = Future.traverse(context.children)(child => (child ? "baz").mapTo[Int])

      val aggFut = for{
        f1 <- fut1
        f2 <- fut2
      } yield SomeResult(f1, f2.toList)

      aggFut pipeTo sender

    case "bar" =>
      sender ! 2
  }
}

class ChildActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case "baz" =>
      sender ! 1
  }
}
```

Then you could test it with this code:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

val system = ActorSystem("foo")
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[ParentActor])
val result = actor ? "foo"

import system._
result onComplete{
  case tr => println(tr)
}
```

When you run this, it should print `Success(SomeResult(2,List(1, 1)))`.

A couple of things here.  First, using `mapTo` allows the types to be known as opposed to having to deal with `Any`.  Second, `pipeTo` is a good option here to avoid closing over the sender and it also simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: Excellent answer.  For those coming across this in their searches, I was also not sending a result back from the (self ? "workhorseStats"), and of course this caused it to time out.  The advice about not having to close over the sender is also very helpful.  @cmbaxter, thank you for the thorough response it was EXACTLY what I was shooting for.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trivial way to combine Futures.  For example (without akka):

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val promiseInt = Promise[Int]
  val promiseString = Promise[String]

  val futureInt = promiseInt.future
  val futureString = promiseString.future

  case class Special(i: Int, s: String)

  futureInt.onSuccess { case(i) =>
    futureString.onSuccess { case(s) =>
      println(Special(i, s))
    }
  }

  promiseInt.success(3)
  promiseString.success("no")
  Thread.sleep(100)
```

The order in which the two futures are completed is irrelevant.  You can try inverting the two success triggers and you will get the same result.

I am using `Promise` here only to build a running example; it has nothing to do with combining the Futures.